# Conditional export in ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

Let's say you're developing a polyfill and don't want to shim a class if it already exists in the browser. How can this be done in ES6? The following is not valid because `exports` is not a statement:

```
if (typeof Foo === 'undefined') {
  export class Foo { ... }
}
```

If the condition above evaluates to `false`, the importing script should get the browser built-in.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`export` should be static. For conditional exports CommonJS modules and `exports` can be used.

It should be handled with ES6 modules this way:

```
export let Foo;

if (window.Foo === undefined) {
  Foo = class Foo { ... }
} else {
  Foo = window.Foo;
}
```

For platform-independent solution (`this` may not be equal to global in transpiled code) `window` can be replaced with

```
const root = (() => eval)()('this');
if (root.Foo === undefined) {
...
```

This exploits binding feature of ES6 modules which was designed this way [to handle cyclic dependencies](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#cyclic-dependencies-in-ecmascript-6) and explained greatly [here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html).

The code above [transpiles to](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=export%20let%20Foo%3B%0A%0Aif%20%28window.Foo%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%29%20%7B%0A%20%20Foo%20%3D%20class%20Foo%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20Foo%20%3D%20window.Foo%3B%0A%7D%0A&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20||%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20||%20node.over%20||%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20||%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20||%20node.over%20||%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D)

```
...
var Foo = exports.Foo = void 0;

if (window.Foo === undefined) {
  exports.Foo = Foo = function Foo() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Foo);
  };
} else {
  exports.Foo = Foo = window.Foo;
}
```

In this case export is not conditional, but `Foo` value that is bound to this export is conditional.

Answer (score 13):

`export` syntax must be at the top-level scope of a module because you are declaring what exports exist. You are free to conditionally assign them a value though, like

```
export let Foo = global.Foo;

if (typeof Foo === 'undefined'){
    Foo = class { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above methods did not work well for me with Webpack. Conditionally bailing out caused Webpack warnings which increased bundle size by 20KB before minification.

Webpack plugins have optimisation which kicks in for production builds. The following code worked for me without increasing the bundle size.

```
let comp = null;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  comp = require('./MyDevComp').default;
}
```

The above conditional require did not increase the bundle size for production builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline conditional (ternary) operator.

```
const IS_DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

export const GET = IS_DEV ? POST : undefined
```