# Importing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

When one imports a specific value from another file, does the entire file that has been exported from run in the file importing? For example if I wanted to import the function "hello" from file b, into file a, would file b run in file a?

An example being:

File A:

```
import {func} from 'fileB.js';
```

File B:

```
let func = function(){...}
console.log(`Hello`);
export {func};
```

Would `Hello` appear in the console of file A, and if it would, under what circumstances. For example, would it be when the import statement is run, or when the `func` is called. If it would not run, are there any ways to make it so it does. For example if I exported the entire file (if that's possible) would the `Hello` appear under certain circumstances?

Comment: "*the console of file A*" - a file doesn't have a separate console. You get a single global `console` for each execution environment (e.g. webpage, or `node` application).

Comment: "*does the entire file that has been exported from run in the file importing*" - no, the exporting module runs **before** the importing module, in its own scope. And notice that it only runs once to initialise, no matter how often/where you import it.

Comment: https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/introduction-to-es6-modules-49956f580da https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_modules.html

Answer (score 2):

The imported file will be run. An easy way to both understand and remember this is [dynamic exports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39584164/1470607):

```js
export let Foo;

if (window.Foo === undefined) {
  Foo = class Foo { ... }
} else {
  Foo = window.Foo;
}
```

In order to know what was exported to begin with, the code needs to be run. Otherwise, it would be equal to solving the halting problem.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using webpack import or require

declare like this

```
const Logger = function() {

}
export { Logger };
```

use it

```
import { Logger } from '../class/Logger';
let logger = new Logger();
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. The question is not how to export and import files. OP wanted to know if the files run when imported.