# Test module's global variables in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a module that I want to test:

```
var array = []; //<--- mobule local array

var Deleter = {
    DeleteNumb: function(number) {
        console.log("TEST", array); //<--- Console
        var index = array.indexOf(number);

        if(index != -1) {
            array.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
};

module.exports = Deleter;
```

And I have a test file throught which I am trying to test this file:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var Deleter = require("../DELETE.js");

describe("Testing Deleter", function() {
    it("DeleteNumb", function() {
        var array = [1,2,3,4,5]; // <--- test arrray

        Deleter.DeleteNumb(3);

        expect(array).to.be.length(4);
    });
});
```

I want to test if an *array* variable is indeed spliced if I call *DeleteNumb* function. But in the console I get: "TEST: [ ]", because *array* variable that is local to the module being tested is indeed empty. My question is how to modify that local *array* for my testing? I do not want to parse the *array* as an argument for *DeleteNumb*. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unit testing of private functions with mocha and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097603/unit-testing-of-private-functions-with-mocha-and-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was to add my DELETE.js local array to exports like that:

```
module.exports.array = array;
module.exports.Deleter = Deleter;
```

And then in the test file I could modify that local array as I wanted:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var Deleter = require("../DELETE.js").Deleter;
var testarray = require("../DELETE.js").array;

describe("Testing Deleter", function() {
    it("DeleteNumb", function() {
        testarray.push(1,2,3,4,5);//modifying DELETE.js array using module.exports reference

        Deleter.DeleteNumb(3);

        expect(testarray).to.be.length(4);
    });
});
```