# how to test private function outside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I have a private function outside component. It sounds more convenient to do test for function alone better than test it inside MyComponent, but it's private not exported.

```
function func(){
 return something;
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

render <SomeComponent someProp={func()} />
}
```

**I use `mocha` and `enzyme` for test and I wonder if there is anyway to test private function rather than test it inside the component.**

Comment: Yeah, export it?

Comment: you missing the point here, in this case you are removing the concept of private functions

Comment: You can't test private functions, and they're not supposed to be tested in isolation as they're supposed to be part of the internal implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unit testing of private functions with mocha and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097603/unit-testing-of-private-functions-with-mocha-and-node-js)

Comment: it's not duplicated since it has react component being used and there must some smart solution to test the function maybe through component instance.
First you suggested to export it, then not testing it and now you refer to it as duplicated. I am not sure if you trying to help here!

Comment: If you want to test it in isolation, then export it. If you think it's private and should not be exported, then you need to test through your other code. I don't see how React can help you with that or is linked to the problem. And Yes I'm trying to help. otherwise I won't be looking at your question.

Comment: well, there's a tag and example related to react

Answer (score 3):

`func` is defined in module scope. It's not possible to reach variables outside the scope they were defined in JavaScript.

Even if `func` were exported, it would be impossible to provide proper unit tests for it, i.e. test `func` in one test, then test a unit depends on `func` (`MyComponent`) in another test with `func` being mocked/spied. `func` is referred within the module, its calls cannot be spied or stubbed.

In order to be fully testable, `func` needs to be either class method, this makes sense if `func` and `MyComponent` are related. Or move `func` to another module. In this case it's possible to mock the module, or as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855968/3731501), due to how ES modules work, `func` import could be mocked/spied on module `*` import.

Comment: agree with making func as class method which makes sense but i was trying to keep the logic outside the component, which turns out it is test headache

Comment: Yes. On the other hand, if it isn't strictly tied to current class and may be used outside the class then it doesn't deserve to be a part of this module, that's what common testability concerns suggest.

Comment: You can export the function and test it directly by destructuring your import. I've included an example below.

Comment: @dysfunc You won't be able to spy or mock `func` this way. Btw, it's no longer can be called 'private', because it's not.

Comment: That's also not true. You can import the module using `*` which outputs the module object `import * as MyComponent from './myComponent';` and then you can `spy` or `stub` the method from there `someLib.spy(MyComponent, 'func')`

Comment: @dysfunc This won't work if `func` is referred directly inside same module like in this case. There will be a spy but it won't be called.

Comment: @estus I stand corrected on this. You're correct given the context, my apologies. If you edit this answer (add a space or something) I'll upvote this since its both educational and valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179567/discussion-between-dysfunc-and-estus).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get any value from unit tests for private methods.

Why do you may want that?

1. To increase test coverage KPI. But once private methods are called by public - they will be taken into account anyway.
2. To ensure everything is working... But making tests for private methods may lead to:

   a. tests are broken while component as a part of system works fine(say, private method has been changed, renamed or removed... but not tests for it) - false negative

   b. tests for private methods are fine, but component is broken(say, private method is needed to be called but it is not) - false positive

Comment: This is really helpful.
Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: As for a, it's perfectly ok, failed test is a thing you expect when you do significant changes to the code. As for b, this is solved by spying on a function, this isn't possible if a function resides in same module and isn't a method.

Comment: I don't agree with this. There is a ton of value in testing private methods directly especially if they perform transforms or contain a decent amount of logic. Why not ensure all the private method use cases & edge cases are covered? You have to write tests for the component which will cover the majority of the use cases for the private function but more often than not someone new to the codebase misuses that function and the tests don't account for that so it goes unnoticed. It's better to be thorough than to write tests with tunnel vision.

Comment: @dysfunc so there is a piece of complex logic. and it is not exposed. so it cannot be reused somewhere else. so it is either so unique that make sense just in single place and specific case or it is complicated not complex and should be decomposed for reusability.

Comment: If the function is a utility/common function it should be moved to its own module and tested independently/thoroughly but why not test everything for a given module? If the class depends on that function to do something to in order to function properly it should be tested in its entirety

Comment: @dysfunc because of efficiency. making test for every single method does not mean there are no error inside. but it definitely mean we need to make double work on every single change inside. even renaming. and it means either less performance or a one will avoid refactoring in any cost because it would mean rewriting tons of unit tests.

Comment: on contrast our unit tests for public API not only are testing for errors but also ensures we don't miss breaking change in API for some component. It's crucial since we don't test mix of components in unit tests but using mocks/stubs. So if API is changed and we have not expected that(unit tests fails for public API) it means system may break in some place where it's integrated.

Comment: you've officially lost me. how does performance come into play? because we are adding 20-100 lines of additional test code? I can run 10k tests using mocha in about a minute... so let's not use that as an argument. Also, if things change you need to change your tests and if things are failing your tests are doing their job.

Comment: I guess will have to agree to disagree

Comment: @dysfunc c'mon, it's not about perfomance of execution(which is also important - I saw how developers switched off git hooks because unit tests took 10 minutes to run). It's about performance of making things. Writing the tests is not a goal by itself.