# Testing not exported node methods of a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, tdd

Here is a normal node module. With some functions that are not all exported, but they needed to test

```
var foo1 = function () { console.log("Foo1"); }
var foo2 = function () { console.log("Foo2"); }
var foo3 = function () { console.log("Foo3"); }

module.exports = {
  foo1: foo1,
  foo2: foo2
}
```

Anybody knows how to test foo3? Normally I test modules with node-sandboxed-module. But there is only possible to mock given things for the module, but I can not change the scope of methods.

Sample for testing module with node-sandboxed-module:

```
var SandboxedModule = require('sandboxed-module');
var user = SandboxedModule.require('./user', {
  requires: {'mysql': {fake: 'mysql module'}},
  globals: {myGlobal: 'variable'},
  locals: {myLocal: 'other variable'},
});
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just also export foo3, prefixing it with a underscore denotes that it is a private function, for example `_foo3: foo3`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access and test an internal (non-exports) function in a node.js module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874208/how-to-access-and-test-an-internal-non-exports-function-in-a-node-js-module)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot change the scoping rules of the language. But you can get around this. You can export an environment variable, and if the variable exists, you can export `foo3` as well. Like this

```
module.exports = {
  foo1: foo1,
  foo2: foo2
}

if (process.env.TESTING) {
    module.exports.foo3 = foo3;
}
```

So, the testcases can test `foo3`, just like they test other exported functions. But, in the production environment, since `TESTING` environment variable will not be there, `foo3` will not be exported.

Also, using `_` in the function's name is understood as, the function/variable is for internal use, no external code should be relying on that function/variable and it is subjected to change without any notice.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, it seems to work.

**sample.js**

```
function double(p2) {
  return p2*2
}

module.exports = function(p, p2) {
 return "Hi "+p+", double "+p2+" = "+double(p2)
}
```

**sample_test.js**

```
function load(file_name) {
  global.module = {}
  const contents = require('fs').readFileSync(file_name, 'utf8');
  const vm = require('vm')
  new vm.Script(contents).runInThisContext();
}


load("./sample.js")

console.log(global.module.exports("Jim","10"))
console.log(double(2))
```

**output**

```
Hi Jim, double 10 = 20
4
```